# Solving differential equation $x^2y''-xy'+y=0, x>0$ with non-constant coefficients using characteristic equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Whenever you deal with non-constant coefficients you usually use Laplace transform to solve a given differential equation, at least that's how how I learned it.

But how would you solve the equation using the characteristic equation?

I've got $x^2r^2-xr+1=0$, but not sure where to go from here? I am asked to obtain one solution from the equation.

Comment: In general, Laplace transform technique  if for linear ode's with constant coefficients. However, in some cases, it can be used to solve linear ode's with non constant coefficients.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Problem Version 1:**

We are given:

$$\tag 1 x^2y''+y=0, ~~x \gt 0$$

This is a Euler-Cauchy type DEQ.

We can let $y = x^m$, so we have: $y'(x) = mx^{m-1}, ~~y''(x) = m(m-1)x^{m-2}$.

Substituting this back into $(1)$, yields:

$x^2y''+ y = x^2(m(m-1)x^{m-2}) + x^m = x^m(m^2 - m + 1) = 0$.

So, we have a characteristic equation:

$$m^2 - m + 1 \rightarrow m_{1,2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \pm \dfrac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Now, because we are given $x \gt 0$ (if not, all the $x$ terms would have absolute values), we can write:

$$\displaystyle y(x) = y_1(x) + y_2(x) = c_1 x^{m_1} + c_2 x^{m_2} = c_1 x^{\large \frac{1}{2} + \frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}} + c_2 x^{\large \frac{1}{2} - \frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2}}$$

Using Euler's identity, some algebra, and the fact that $x \gt 0$, we can write this as:

$$y(x) = c_1 \sqrt{x} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln x\right) + c_2 \sqrt{x} \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln x\right)$$

**Problem Version 2:**

$$\tag 2 x^2y''-x y'+ y = 0, x \gt 0$$

This requires the use of the Frobenius method to find a solution near $x = 0$. I will assume you are studying this, so I am going to map it out for you and you fill in the missing details.

Here, we want the form $y'' + P(x) y' + Q(x) y = 0$, so:

- Dividing both sides by $x^2$, we get $P(x) = -\dfrac{1}{x}, ~ Q(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^2}$
- So, $x = 0$ is a singular point and the method of Frobenius is usable.

Next, to use this method, we substitute $y$ and its derivatives from:

- $\displaystyle y = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{\lambda+n}$
- $y' = \lambda a_0 x^{\lambda - 1} + \ldots (\lambda+n+1)a_{n+1}x^{\lambda+n}+\ldots$
- $y'' = \lambda(\lambda-1)a_0x^{\lambda-2} + (\lambda + n + 1)(\lambda+n)a_{n+1}x^{\lambda + n -1}+\ldots$

We substitute these into $(2)$, collect like terms and set them equal to zero. This gives us:

$$x^{\lambda}(\lambda-1)^2a_0 + x^{\lambda + 1} \lambda^2 a_1 + \ldots x^{\lambda + n}\left((\lambda + n)^2 - 2(\lambda + n) + 1\right)a_n + \ldots = 0$$

From this, we get:

- $\tag 3 (\lambda - 1)^2 a_0 = 0$ and generally
- $\tag 4 \left((\lambda + n)^2 - 2(\lambda + n) +1\right)a_n = 0$

The first expression is called the indicial equation and it gives us: $(\lambda-1)^2 = 0$, which has a double root $\lambda_{1,2} = 1$, which we substitute into the second equation, yielding $n^2 a_n = 0$, which implies $a_n = 0, ~ n \ge 1$, thus:

$$y_1(x) = a_0 x$$

Now, we want a second linearly independent solution, but the indicial equations roots are equal. This complicates matters! To find a second family of solutions, we first solve for $a_n$ in terms of $\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is thought of as an independent variable in $(4)$. We obtain $a_n = 0$ for $n \ge 1$ and then substitute back into the original $y$ we used, with $\lambda$ as the independent variable, so:

$$y = y(\lambda, x) = a_0x^\lambda$$

Another family of solutions to $(2)$ can be obtained by:

$$y_2 = \dfrac{\partial y(\lambda, x)}{\partial \lambda} ~\text{evaluated at}~ \lambda = 1$$

Since (recall that we are given $x \gt 0$, else we would need absolute values):

- $y = a_0x^\lambda = a_0 e^{\lambda \ln x}$
- $\dfrac{\partial y(\lambda, x)}{\partial \lambda} = a_0 \ln x e^{\lambda \ln x} = a_0 x^\lambda \ln x$ , and evaluated at $\lambda = 1$, yields: $a_0 x \ln x = y_1(x) \ln x$
- This gives us the second solution as $y_2(x) = a_0 x^\lambda \ln x$.

Putting this together, our solution is (test this by replacing it in the original DEQ and see that is satisfies it):

$$y(x) = y_1(x) + y_2(x) = c_1 x + c_2 x \ln x$$

Lastly, it is worth noting the [*Wolfram Alpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+y%27%27+-+x+y+%2By+%3D+0%2C+x+%3E+0) finds a solution using modified Bessel and the Gamma functions.

Comment: I am sorry, ommited the middle term $-xy'$ accidentally. Fixed my question. Please, could you update the answer? I got the idea, just want to make sure this is correct.

Comment: Excellent write-up! +1

Comment: Nice update, Amzoti! You went all out!

Answer (score 5):

Transfer your equation with $x = e^t$

Then $\frac{dx}{dt} = e^t$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx} = e^{-t}\frac{dy}{dt} = x^{-1} \frac{dy}{dt}$$

So $$x \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt}$$

Do the same for $x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and you shall get the result

$$x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - \frac{dy}{dt}$$

I have omited the calculation part and hope you can do it for yourself. Now put all these values to your differential equation and you shall get the following

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - \frac{dy}{dt} + y =0 $$

Now you know how to solve.

Please check the calculation part only.